# How to check MimeType of a media in android

Tags: android, video

How to check MimeType of a media in android?

```
public boolean isVideoFile(String path) {

     String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(path);
     return mimeType != null && mimeType.indexOf("video") == 0 || mimeType.indexOf("audio")== 0;

}
```

Comment: What's the issue with that code? Do you get any value in the String variable `mimeType` ?

Comment: I am getting 'java.lang.NullPointerException' if path is null, I have solved it by check if(null!=path). Is there any solution without checking path as null

Comment: Is this the changed code?

Comment: @user-CK _"...without checking path as null"_ what's so bad about code that checks the existence of data before trying to use it? What else do you expect to happen if path is null (none existent)?

Comment: Yes. At the time of isVideoFile(path) call, I am checking path is !=null